# How to define which file to use according to user response to dropdown?

Tags: python, function, user-interface

I have a Gooey GUI where the user can input a single file with some information about assets that will be depreciated. However, the method of depreciation changes according to different countries. Therefore, I also added a dropdown button so the user can choose the country.

This is code I have so far (w/o the imports):

```
@Gooey(program_name="DEPRECIATION")
def parse_args():
    parser = GooeyParser()

    parser.add_argument('Fixed_Assets_File',
                        action='store',
                        widget='FileChooser',
                        help="Excel file with all fixed assets to depreciate")

    parser.add_argument('Country',
                        widget='Dropdown',
                        choices=['Germany','France','Norway',
                                 'Poland','UK','NL','Sweden',
                                 'Russia','Spain',],
                        help="Choose the country")

    parser.add_argument('Output_File_Name',
                        action='store',
                        help="Name of the output file with .xlsx")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
def country_selection(mapping_file):
    if 'Germany' in args.Country:
        mapping = pd.read_excel("germany_depreciation.xlsx")
    elif 'France' in args.Country:
        mapping = pd.read_excel("france_depreciation.xlsx")
    elif 'Norway' in args.Country:
        mapping = pd.read_excel("norway_depreciation.xlsx")
    elif 'Poland' in args.Country:
        mapping = pd.read_excel("poland_depreciation.xlsx")
    elif 'UK' in args.Country:
        mapping = pd.read_excel("uk_depreciation.xlsx")
    elif 'NL' in args.Country:
        mapping = pd.read_excel("nl_depreciation.xlsx")
    elif 'Sweden' in args.Country:
        mapping = pd.read_excel("sweden_depreciation.xlsx")
    elif 'Russia' in args.Country:
        mapping = pd.read_excel("russia_depreciation.xlsx")
    elif 'Spain' in args.Country:
        mapping = pd.read_excel("spain_depreciation.xlsx")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    assets = args.Fixed_Assets_File
    country = args.Country
    print("You chose", country)
```

As you may have noticed, there is a master file for each country with all the necessary information and the different categories for the assets. I already have the code I want to implement for the formulas/depreciation calculations. I could just copy and paste it into each if statement, but that would make the code horribly long.

Is there a way to tell Gooey/Python to choose which file to import according to the country the user selects in the dropdown button?

For ex: if they choose Poland, all the other master files are ignored and only Poland is imported and defined as the "mapping"

ps: when I say master files, I mean the ones being imported from excel in the format: nameofthecountry_depreciation.xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dict linking the country to the respective master file.

```py
country_mapping = {
    'Germany': 'germany_depreciation.xlsx',
    'France': 'france_depreciation.xlsx',
    # other countries
}
```

Then you can call:

```py
mapping = pd.read_excel(country_mapping[args.Country])
```

Then you can remove your function `country_selection()`.

You can also use the `country_mapping` dict to populate the country choices in the parser by calling `country_mapping.keys()`.